# Is there a more efficient way of generating a float to a specific decimal value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I basically want a float that is accurate to the **sixth** place after the decimal.

Something like `0.123456`

This is what I tried to do:

```
irb(main):001:0> rand = rand(1.000000..100.000000)
=> 97.63428182481212
```

But I obviously don't want it that precise, so I decided to do

```
irb(main):002:0> rand = rand(1.000000..100.000000).round(6)
=> 12.944086
```

But now there's an extra step involved, when it seems like I should be able to do it another way. I am going to have to generate several hundred numbers, so I am not sure if I should screw it and just use `.round()`.

Comment: Remember the way a number is rendered is rather arbitrary and internally it will always have more information than is shown. All floating point numbers are approximations when represented in decimal. If you need six places precisely then you need a fixed-point method like [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) can provide.

Comment: Rounding "several hundred numbers" should be relatively fast. On my machine rounding one thousand numbers took 1.5ms. So, it's probably fast enough for your needs.

Comment: @tadman, yep, you are right. I ended up doing a migration from integer to a decimal with a scale of 6 and max precision of 16.@Jared Beck, yeah, I don''t know why I was worried.

Comment: If you got it working it's worth adding a self-answer with the code you used.

Comment: Having a log of digits below the decimal point does not mean that it is accurate. It only means that it not a best fit for decimal expression.

Comment: If the sole answer is satisfactory, please consider selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
rand(1000000)/1000000.0
#=> 0.071203
```